# Build curves of populations in function of time

Tags: r

In my work i'm studying a lot of varieties of maize.

I would like to determinate the area under the curve during flowering (male and female) of these varieties.

I used the package DescTools and the function AUC (area under the curve). I converted my dates as a numeric vector. So my scipt is:

```r
a<-XAUC$Date.flowering.male
 
b<-XAUC$Date.flowering.female

c<- XAUC$....
```

Here is my issue, because i would like to identify `c` as the population as function of time. How can i do this?

In this picture: the first graph is what i have and the second is what i would like to have.

[image]

and then the end of my script will be:

```r
AUCfemale<-AUC(b,c,method = c("trapezoid"))
 
AUCmale<-AUC(a,c,method = c("trapezoid"))
 
Airdiff<-AUCmale-AUCfemale
```

---

Data

```r
XAUC <- structure(list(Varietes = c("Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone"), ligne.rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pied = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7), `Date.floraison.mâle` = c(7.29, 8.02, 8.01, 8.03, 8.04), Date.floraison.femelle = c(8.1, 8.17, 8.11, 8.25, 8.17 ), ASIi = c(12, 15, 10, 22, 13), Hauteur.des.pieds = c(230, 228, 226, 240, 233), Hauteur.des.soies = c(123, 118, 116, 124, 122), Date.floraison.mâle.graph = c(29, 33, 32, 34, 35), Date.floraison.femelle.graph = c(41, 48, 42, 56, 48)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c("6" = 6L, "10" = 10L, "20" = 20L, "21" = 21L, "24" = 24L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Please share some sample data so that we can reproduce your problem. `dput()` is a good way to share data because it is copy/pasteable and it includes all class and structure information. For example, `dput(XAUC[1:15, ])` might work well to share the first 15 rows of `XAUC`  if `XAUC` is a data frame.

Comment: structure(list(Varietes = c("Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", 
"Abelastone", "Abelastone"), ligne.rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pied = c(1, 
2, 3, 6, 7), Date.floraison.mâle = c(7.29, 8.02, 8.01, 8.03, 
8.04), Date.floraison.femelle = c(8.1, 8.17, 8.11, 8.25, 8.17
), ASIi = c(12, 15, 10, 22, 13), Hauteur.des.pieds = c(230, 228, 
226, 240, 233), Hauteur.des.soies = c(123, 118, 116, 124, 122
), Date.floraison.mâle.graph = c(29, 33, 32, 34, 35), Date.floraison.femelle.graph = c(41, 
48, 42, 56, 48)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"),

Comment: na.action = structure(c(`6` = 6L, `10` = 10L, 
`20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, `24` = 24L), class = "omit"))

Comment: I wrote :  dput(XAUC[1:5, ]). I made a condition before to isolate varieties. I have a very few data because it's only false data. I'm just trying to write a script that will help me in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks, please put that in the question with proper formatting, not down here in comments.

Comment: ok, r2evans dit it

Comment: Your data contains fields for dates (fractional days?) and height, but I see nothing for population size. Is that what your `*.graph` columns are for? It might help to describe (briefly) what each of your variables mean in the context of your plot.

Comment: Ok, so to use the function AUC i had to do change my dates in a a numeric form. So columns "graph" are just my dates. To be clear it's the day to july to August, so 62 days. My colums "Hauteur des soies", "Hauteurs des pieds", and "ASIi" are not usefull here. The colums "Pied" is just the number that I give to the plant that i study. Here, population size is just 5 plants of "Abelastone".

Comment: That is helpful, so you want effectively `Date.floraison.mâle.graph` on the x-axis and effectively row-number on the y-axis, repeated for `femelle`?

Comment: Also, I'm inferring that there are different `Varietes` and `ligne.rep`, suggesting that you may want either different lines in the same plot for each `Varietes` and gender, or you will want to facet by them. It's not hard to plot *this* date, just thinking ahead to the next step.

Comment: what do you mean by "row-number"?

Comment: Just that, row number within the data. The `29` and `41` are Xs, and their Ys are both `1`; `33` and `48` Xs will have a Y of `2`, etc.

Comment: (as I play with it, I wonder ... the `Date*graph` variables are not in order, is that meaningful?)

Comment: what do you mean by "row-number"? But yes it's what i want to do. For example here, i have 5 person of "Abelastone". I would like to build the curves of Date.floraison.mâle.graph (x) and Date.floraison.femelle.graph(x) in function of my 5 persons. And yes it exists to types of ligne rep: 1 and 2. Here in my exemple it's a 1.

Comment: I don't know if the order is important. But if we want to create croissants curves maybe!